# Why does `viewmodel.getStore()` return null

Tags: gridview, extjs, viewmodel

In my application, written in sencha 6.5 modern, I have a viewmodel that is "called" inside the widget's panel title, with the simple config in the panel:

```
{
    xtype: 'grid',
    layout: 'fit',
    flex: 1,

    store: {
        type: 'entry',
    },
    viewModel: 'entryoverview',

    columns:[
        {
            text: 'event',
            cell: {
                xtype: 'widgetcell',
                widget: {

                    xtype: 'panel',
                    collapsible: true,
                    collapsed: true,
                    collapseToolText: 'ikke',
                    bind: {
                        title: '{showTitle}',

                    },
                }
            }
        },
    ],
}
```

Now the viewmodel is as follow:

```
Ext.define('AllSports.view.entry.EntryOverviewViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

    alias: 'viewmodel.entryoverview',

    stores: [{
        entrystore: {
            type: 'entry',
        }
    }],

    formulas: {
        showTitle: {
            get: function() {
                debugger;
                let a = this.getStore('entrystore');
                return 'event: ';
            }
        },
    }
});
```

Now I notice that the store is "empty" (`null`) however I also notice that I'm linking against the global store, and not creating a viewmodel per cell.

What I would like to achieve is that each "panel" inside the grid has its own viewmodel, so that the display is something like a list with:

```
event: A
event: B
```

So how can I make each viewmodel have a reference to the correct "store entry"/"model" inside the enclosing grid?

Answer (score 1):

> `viewmodel.getStore()` return null

Instead of this `viewmodel.getStore()` you need to use like `viewmodel.getStore('entrystore')` so it will return the your `entrystore`.

[viewModel.getStore(key)](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/modern/Ext.app.ViewModel.html#method-getStore) gets a store configured via the stores configuration.

And for setting title of panel inside of `widgetcell` you can use `painted` event and get the record inside of that method. After that you can set title using [`setTitle()`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/modern/Ext.Panel.html#placeholder-accessor-setTitle) method or you can also use `bind` config here.

You can check here with working **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2krj)**.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.define('Entry', {

            extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

            alias: 'store.entry',

            fields: [{
                name: 'eventName',
                type: 'string'
            }],

            data: [{
                eventName: 'A'
            }, {
                eventName: 'B'
            }]
        });

        Ext.define('EntryOverviewViewModel', {
            extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',

            alias: 'viewmodel.entryoverview',

            stores: {
                entrystore: {
                    type: 'entry'
                }
            }
        });

        let grid = Ext.create({
            xtype: 'grid',

            fullscreen: true,

            title: 'Grid Demo',

            layout: 'fit',

            flex: 1,

            viewModel: {
                type: 'entryoverview'
            },

            bind: {
                store: '{entrystore}'
            },

            columns: [{
                text: 'Event',
                flex: 1,
                cell: {
                    xtype: 'widgetcell',
                    widget: {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        collapsible: true,
                        collapsed: true,
                        collapseToolText: 'ikke',
                        listeners: {
                            painted: function (panel) {
                                let row = panel.up('gridrow');
                                panel.setTitle('event : ' + row.getRecord().get('eventName'));
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        });

        console.log(grid.getViewModel().getStore('entrystore'))
    }
});
```

Comment: If you check the code I'm actually using `this.getStore('entrystore')` - which should work? I've always had a real adversion to using "painted" events and the like, it brings code into the view, or if one uses an event in the controller it binds the controller and view tightly together. (Hence why I wish to use viewmodels to abstract this code away, where the bindings act as glue).

Comment: Yes I have checked but in your code you have not bide the store by `entrystore`. If you not bind that `entrystore` store then it will not create. So tried first with bind that `entrystore` to your grid.